# How is luck replenished?

Tags: android, knights-of-pen-and-paper

Luck seems to replenish at random for me. Does anyone know at what rate it replenishes, or how I can replenish it myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

luck is replenished via gameplay. The more you play, the more it replenishes. If you die or stop playing it should turn into 0.