# At what rate is luck replenished?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

I am aware of this question:
[How is luck replenished?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92841/how-is-luck-replenished?rq=1)

But I am interested in the actual rate at which luck is replenished, and what is the metric for its increase?  Is it battle based, or game time, or what is it?

Hopefully guilherme is still lurking around here.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of the game, (the actual updated version), the luck is only affected by three items in the game. A ring, a die and a passive skill from one of the characters. The luck doesn't replenish or change during game time anymore.

Get the latest version, buying it on steam, ios or android stores.

Cheers!